# I am trying to create a page with full width using Oslo master page, can anyone help?

Tags: oslo

I am attempting to create a full width style page using the Oslo masterpage. I found an similar question on this site and the answer to that one was to add the following piece of code to a custom css.

```
.contentwrapper {
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}

#titleAreaBox {
   margin: auto 0px!important;
   padding:0;
}
```

I added this and it helped solved the majority of my issues. But I found that I am still getting a small amount of padding on the left/right and bottom sides of the page. I have attached an image to better explain the issue.

[image]

Ian

Comment: I would recommend you update the Image and remove the site URL

Answer (score 0):

There is another element with Id `contentbox`. You need to remove padding from that element

```
.ms-pub-contentLayout {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

[image]